# Error cargar datos en la factura

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo la siguiente macro para el registro de datos en la factura [image: esta es la estructura de la factura, tengo un error en FilasFactura error 1004, error en el método 'Range de objeto' _ global, la tabla que se encuentra dentro de la estructura de la factura que contiene el codigo, descripcion, cantidad precio unitario y subtotal se llama Factura y de ahi necesito la primera columna y me indica que no la reconoce]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub GuardarFactura()

Dim NombreHoja As String
Dim HojaDestino As Range
Dim NuevaFila As Integer
Dim FilasFactura As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NumFactura As Integer

NombreHoja = "DetalleFacturas"

> ***FilasFactura = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Factura[CODIGO]"))***

NumFactura = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factura").Range("F5").Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NombreHoja)

      For i = 1 To FilasFactura
          
          Set HojaDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NombreHoja).Range("B6").CurrentRegion
          NuevaFila = HojaDestino.Rows.Count + 1
          .Cells(NuevaFila, 1).Value = Date
          .Cells(NuevaFila, 2).Value = NumFactura
          .Cells(NuevaFila, 3).Value = Range("F7").Value
          
          For j = 1 To 5
           .Cells(NuevaFila, j + 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factura").Cells(9 + 1, 1 + j)
           Next j
                    
       Next i

End With

MsgBox ("Registro Exitoso")

End Sub
```

Comment: El error lo tengo en la siguiente línea de código FilasFactura = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Factura[CODIGO]"))
Me aparece error 1004 Error en el método 'Range de objeto Global'

Comment: Prueba con `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factura").Range("Factura[CODIGO]"))`

Comment: No me esta detectando la tabla, como se evidencia en las imágenes cargadas la tabla se llama factura sus encabezados son codigo, producto, cantidaad p/unitario y subtotal, pero me arroja ese error

Comment: Yo he creado una tabla llamada Factura y me funciona todo perfectamente. Asegúrate que la hoja activa sea la de la tabla y que el nombre de esta no tenga espacios en blanco al final o caracteres no visibles. Renómbrala

Comment: Para saber el nombre de cada columna asignado: 1) Clic en cualquier sitio de la tabla. 2) Ir al tabulador Diseño de Tabla. 3) Marcar la casilla Fila de encabezado.

Comment: El error relacionado con tu pregunta tiene que estar dentro de la pregunta, no en un comentario.